# Something really weird with C++ exp() function

Tags: c++, square-root, exp

When tying to implement **mySqrt** function in C++, I used the exp() function like this:

```
int mySqrt(int x) {
    // For x = 2147395600
    cout << exp(0.5*log(x)) << "  ";     // It prints 46340
    return exp(0.5*log(x));              // But returns 46339
}
```

I tried to google the reason for this behavior but could not find anything. I even tried using *double* but still the same output.

Any explanation for this?

Comment: [`46339` is returned instead of `46349`.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ODHhVyFT4iKCwzGb)

Comment: @MikeCAT I am sorry, that's what I meant. Updated the question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
using std::cout;

int mySqrt(int x) {
    // For x = 2147395600
    cout << exp(0.5*log(x)) << "  ";     // It prints 46340
    return exp(0.5*log(x));              // But returns 46349
}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << mySqrt(2147395600) << "\n";
    printf("%.30f\n", exp(0.5*log(2147395600)));
    return 0;
}
```

[I got output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0eKP8qc9sba2EHJ3):

```
46340  46339
46339.999999999978172127157449722290
```

It seems the value is rounded when passed to `cout` while truncated when converted to `int`.

Comment: Converting a floating point value (e.g. `double`) to an integral type (like `int`) rounds toward zero.   That is one of the basic conversions specified in the standard.

Comment: @Rakshak If you wonder about the result of `46339.999999999978172127157449722290` then this might be worth to read: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/). ;-)